Automate sending Power BI screenshots via email
I need to take screenshots of different pages of a Power BI report and send these screenshots to a specific list of email addresses.
My main question is: how can I automate the process of taking screenshots of multiple pages?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You can pin pages from the same report or different reports to a Dashboard and then create a subscription. This allows you to share multiple screenshots simultaneously.
From Power BI Service, open your report and select the Pin icon and assignt the page to a Dashboard.

Repeat this process for each page, and then open the Dashboard.
As shown in the image below, you can view all pages in a single Dashboard.
You can now create a subscription to automatically share this Dashboard with anyone in your organization.


Thank you a lot, Agustin! The thing is I need to send it to lots of external emails, which are invalid in the recipients field.
